# Django makemigration generates AlterField without any change on Model

Tags: python, django

When using `makemigrations` in Django, I notice that it generates migrations even for fields that did not changed. What is the reason for this?

Here is the Model that Django generates a new migration for every time I run `makemigrations`

```
class Announcement(OJModel):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        "user.User",
        verbose_name=_("Announcement Owner"),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="owner_announcements",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300, default="", verbose_name=_("Title"))
    description = models.TextField(
        max_length=3000, default="", verbose_name=_("Description")
    )
    estate = models.OneToOneField(
        "announcement.Estate",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name=_("Estate"),
        null=True,
    )
```

Script generated by `makemigrations`:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ("announcement", "0072_auto_20181218_1256"),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name="announcement",
            name="estate",
            field=models.OneToOneField(
                null=True,
                on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE,
                to="announcement.Estate",
                verbose_name="Estate",
            ),
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: can you add the migration script generated?

Comment: @JPG added migration script

Comment: I see you're using gettext for verbose name translation. What translation principle are you using? Standard translation can trigger migration changes. In general you'd want to use lazy translation `ugettext_lazy` in models.

Comment: @Borut I use 'from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _'

Comment: @MohammadHosseinGerami, ok, that's good. I have no other idea.

Comment: This can happen if your local migrations history (as stored in the db) doesn't match the real history and/or db state (which is sometimes the case when switching branches in dev env without making sure you applied / rolled back migrations).  Check what's in your migration history (in the "django_migrations" table) for this app, what  migrations you have in your app's migrations folder, and if the model's table state matches the expected state.

Answer (score 1):

Write like this in models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Announcement(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey('user.User', verbose_name=_('Announcement Owner'), on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='owner_announcements', null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300, default='', verbose_name=_('Title'))
    description = models.TextField(max_length=3000, default='',verbose_name=_('Description'))
    estate = models.OneToOneField('announcement.Estate', on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name=_('Estate'), null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

In admin.py write like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Announcement

# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(Announcement)
```

Save the files and now delete the old migration from migration folder!

Now run these in the command line in manage.py directory:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

Then this:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

It's all done!